# Не отрабатывает событие в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, события

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему событие (на выполнение хранимой процедуры) может не выполняться? Сама процедура работает - проверял. Событие включено, интервал поставлен, может где логи или ошибки посмотреть можно? Работаю в dbForgeStudio. Вот код самого события:

```
CREATE 
    DEFINER = 'user'@'%'
EVENT asteriskcdrdb.ev_for_calls
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' DAY
    STARTS '2018-01-17 23:59:30'
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
    DO 
BEGIN
  CALL procedure1(beginday(CURRENT_DATE()), endday(CURRENT_DATE()), @error);
END;

ALTER EVENT asteriskcdrdb.ev_for_calls
    ENABLE
```

Comment: Вы убеждены, что именно событие не выполняется? Если в действие в самое начало добавить INSERT в отладочную таблицу - будет ли добавлена запись? А если такой INSERT добавить в начало процедуры?

Comment: Говорю, вот эта строка CALL procedure1(beginday(CURRENT_DATE()), endday(CURRENT_DATE()), @error); отлично выполняется. Добавлял вместо нее INSERT на добавление записи в ту же таблицу - не работает.

Comment: А, стесняюсь спросить, Event Scheduler запущен? см. `SHOW PROCESSLIST` - там в списке должен быть процесс `User: event_scheduler` `Command: Daemon`

Comment: Точно, совсем забыл про него!) Большое спасибо!